# Restrict node for anonymous user programmatically

Tags: caching, users

First of all I've seen lot's of threads about restriction, but didn't find what I'm looking for.

So, my goal is to restrict the access for a specific node to anonymous users and when they try to enter that node, it will redirect them to the user/login page.

I was using Content Access module till now. It works like it should, but the problem is when this module is enabled, block caching is not working. As I know the Context module has the same issue.

I have one big menu block and without caching, the website is 4 times slower. When the Content Access module is disabled, the block is cached and the performance is great.

Let's say the url of the page is 'apple'.

I'm looking for a way to restrict only this page programmatically, without breaking the block caching.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Have you considered simply setting the default 403 page to the user login, and restrict the node via a module?   Some other options might be logintoboggan, or r4032login modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7):

```
<?php
// Get the current active node object if present.
$node = menu_get_object();
// Redirect to login page if NID == 42 and user is anonymous.
// User will then go back to node page due to destination being set.
if (   user_is_anonymous() 
    && !empty($node) 
    && !empty($node->nid) 
    && $node->nid == 42
    ) {
  drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/' . $node->nid)), 307);
}
?>
```

[hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7):

```
<?php
$args = arg();
if (   user_is_anonymous()
    && isset($args[0]) && $args[0] == 'node'
    && isset($args[1]) && is_numeric($args[1])
    ) {
  drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/' . $node->nid)), 307);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where should I put that code, Mickey? I have a custom module, but do I have to call some hook for that?

Comment: I would use [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7).

Comment: I think should be <a href="https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7">hook_boot</a> because hook_init is not run in cached pages. Or use hook_init but avoid caching of that node page.

Comment: It works great, Mickey. I think you should edit your answer with adding hook_init(), so I can mark your answer. I've just tested, it doesn't break the block caching. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to correct, you have a syntax error. This line should have another parentheses after the letter 307, so it's gonna be like this: drupal_goto('user/login', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/' . $node->nid), 307));